# Inconsistent behavior from number_format

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, formatting

I'm trying to format a number in a table cell with comma separators between thousands. The number is coming from a custom field generated in Advanced Custom Fields plugin, where it is required to be a number.

(But I've also tried just entering the number directly in the below examples.)

I'm getting the correct number value, but the formatting isn't working. Plus, I get different results from number_format inside a table cell and outside one.

My number is 429000, retrieved by the_field('price').

Here's what I've tried inside the cell:

```
<td class="pl-property-price"><?php number_format( the_field('price')); ?> </td>
<td class="pl-property-price"><?php number_format((int) the_field('price')); ?> </td>
<td class="pl-property-price"><?php number_format( intval(the_field('price'))); ?> </td>
<td class="pl-property-price"><?php number_format( the_field('price'), 0, ".", ","); ?> </td>
```

and some other variations.

No matter what I do, it outputs 429000 without the comma separator.

Now, if I try to echo the value outside the table, using code like this and all the similar variations to the above using

```
<?php echo number_format(the_field('price')); ?>
```

I get 4290000 which adds an extra zero.

I'm puzzled.

Comment: How would like the number to look after formatting?

Comment: @batz I'm looking for 429,000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the function you using is the [the_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) function from of [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com) which is a function that outputs a string so the formatting number_formatt dosent effect the output.

This code:

```
 <?php echo number_format(the_field('price')); ?>
```

The echo does not really print anything, the function the_fields prints the output, that's the reason the number_format function doesn't have any effect on the output.

Try getting the field via different function [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) for example, or you could add the the function the_fields a $format_value argument like you could see in the [docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) .

This should work:

```
<?php echo number_format( get_field( 'price' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: That's it. The echo is needed along with the use of get_field rather than the_field. I just discovered as well.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

- `get_field()`: Returns the value of a specific field.
- `the_field()`: Displays the value of a specific field.

The correct snippet looks like this:

```
<?php echo number_format( get_field( 'price' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to use the `get_field` function instead of `the_field`.

`the_field` echos the value, whereas `get_field` returns a value in which you can pass as the parameter value to the `number_format`.

```
<?php echo number_format(get_field('price')); ?>
```

You can also learn more about [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)